# A C program where a discount is applied on the cheaper item

Tags: c

The program works somewhat but I can't figure out how to make it add the discounted amount to the correct item, basically how the program can tell which item was cheaper apply discount to that item and then add it to the other item that was not discounted (has it's full price since it was more expensive than the other item)

```
#include "stdio.h"
// a program that takes the price of two items, applies a discount on the cheaper item and then calculates the outcome that needs to be paid.
int main()
{
    float item_one;
    float item_two;
    float discount_percentage= 50;
    float discount_amount;
    float total;
    float cheaper_item;

    printf("\n Insert the price of the first item : ");
    scanf("%f", &item_one);

    printf("\n Insert the price of the first item : ");
    scanf("%f", &item_two);

    if ( item_one < item_two)
        cheaper_item = item_one;
    else
        cheaper_item = item_two;

    discount_amount = (discount_percentage*cheaper_item)/100;

    printf ("\n Discount amount : %f \n", discount_amount);

    total = (discount_amount + cheaper_item);

    printf ("Total to pay : %f \n", total);
}
```

Comment: you could use two pointers, `float* cheaperItem` and `float* otherItem`, assign them to the correct items in your `if` statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the calculation of the total that is wrong.
Add the two prices minus the discount :

```
total = (item_one + item_two - discount_amount);
```

Answer (score 0):

The "goto" solution when one starts programming is to "use more variables and more code" trying to wrestle with a problem. This leads to confusion.

The following uses only 3 `float`s (should use `double`s), and, with fewer lines achieves slightly more than the OP.

Notice that variables are declared near to where/when they are needed. In this limited application, `discount` can serve two purposes: the initial rate, and then the (presumed) dollar amount.

It is clear that the discount is calculated from the price of the "cheaper item", then subtracted from the total cost.

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main()
{
    float item_one;
    printf("\n Insert the price of the first item : ");
    scanf("%f", &item_one);

    float item_two;
    printf("\n Insert the price of the second item : "); // Typo
    scanf("%f", &item_two);

    float discount = 0.50; // == 50%

    if (item_one < item_two)
        discount *= item_one; // discount now $
    else
        discount *= item_two; // discount now $

    char *fmt = "%20s: %8.2f\n";
    printf (fmt, "Total Price", item_one + item_two);
    printf (fmt, "Discount amount", discount);
    printf (fmt, "Total cost", item_one + item_two - discount);
}
```

Output

```
 Insert the price of the first item : 100.00

 Insert the price of the second item : 20.00
         Total Price:   120.00
     Discount amount:    10.00
          Total cost:   110.00
```